# Need to calculate when adding coin

Tags: c#

I am building a vending machine and I am stuck on adding coins.

Coin should automatically be calculated when I click on the assigned button But Instead I am just getting the value inside textbox here's the code

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VendingMachine
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void operator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              new Form2().Show();
              this.Hide();
        }



        private void fiveP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            balance.Text = ((double)balance.Text + 0.05).ToString();

        }

        private void tenP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            balance.Clear();
            balance.Text = balance.Text + "0.10";

        }

        private void twentyP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            balance.Clear();
            balance.Text = balance.Text + "0.20";

        }

        private void fiftyP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            balance.Clear();
            balance.Text = balance.Text + "0.50";

        }

        private void onePound_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            balance.Clear();
            balance.Text = balance.Text + "1.00";

        }

        private void twoPound_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            balance.Clear();
            balance.Text = balance.Text + "2.00";

        }

    }
}
```

Coin Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace VendingMachine
{
    [Serializable]
    internal class Coin : ISerializable, IComparable
    {
        public string coinName = "";
        public double coinValue = 0.0;
        public int coinBalance = 0;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.coinName; }
            set { this.coinName = value; }
        }

        public double Value
        {
            get { return this.coinValue; }
            set { this.coinValue = value; }
        }

        public int Balance
        {
            get { return this.coinBalance; }
            set { this.coinBalance = value; }
        }

        public Coin(string coin_name)

        { this.coinName = coin_name; }

        public Coin(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            this.coinValue = (double)info.GetValue("CoinValue", typeof(double));
            this.coinName = (string)info.GetValue("CoinName", typeof(string));
        }

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            info.AddValue("CoinValue", this.coinValue);
            info.AddValue("CoinName", (object)this.coinName);
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Coin)
                return this.Value.CompareTo(((Coin)obj).Value);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("object is not a Coin");
        }

        public static IComparer sortByCoinName()
        {
            return (IComparer)new Coin.sortByCoinNameHelper();
        }

        private class sortByCoinNameHelper : IComparer
        {
            int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
            {
                return ((Coin)a).Name.CompareTo(((Coin)b).Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you know you are doing string *addition* (concatenation) and **no arithmetic operations**

Comment: where are you referencing a `Coin` class in this code?

Comment: How does your Coin class fit into this? It doesn't appear in your question. What type is `balance`?

Comment: balance can't be an `int`, `int` doesn't have a `.Text` property

Comment: If balance was an int, your code would not compile. Can you show us the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: I flagged this question as Low Quality, unsalvageable, due to the multiple comments indicating that the issues the poster is experiencing are not even related to the code which was posted.

Comment: Wow, string math is always a bad idea. Deal with numbers (decimals) first and _only_ use strings for display.

Comment: ok I see that you added the `Coin` class, but I still go back to my original point, the code for the buttons are not interacting with it at all.

Answer (score 1):

if balance is the textbox you are working with, you are clearing it with the button press, erasing whatever was in it prior to the button press, so it will always be `"" +` whatever.  also, you can't add strings like that, `"1.00" + "2.00" == "1.002.00", != "3.00"`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding strings rather than numbers.  You'll need to convert your strings into numbers to add them together, and you shouldn't clear your results first.

For example:

```
private void fiveP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // balance.Clear();    <- You don't need this.
            balance.Text = ((double)balance.Text + 0.05).ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I have tried that method but it still doesn't work. Error Cannot convert type 'string' to 'double'

Comment: So what is in your string? If it can't convert it to a number then it's probably not something that you can add together.

Comment: These are the variables of my Coin class private string coinName = "";
        private double coinValue = 0.0;
        private int coinBalance = 0;

Comment: what do those have to do with the code you posted?  Either you didn't post a complete code sample or you are not referencing those, and if they are private, you can't access them outside the Coin class anyway.

Comment: well not just that, you aren't even calling them in the code sample you posted.

Comment: I think rather than trying to cast a string to double, @FuzzyBear should use `double.Parse(balance.Text)`.

Comment: I would even use double.TryParse() so you can elegantly handle error conditions.

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are using a **string** type for **calculating**.. there is a difference between calculating something and displaying it. in short:

```
float value = 0;

void print()
{
   balance.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", value);
}

private void fiveP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    value += 0.05f;
    print();
}

private void tenP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    value += 0.10f;
    print();

}

private void twentyP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    value += 0.20f;
    print();

}

private void fiftyP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   value += 0.50f;
    print();

}

private void onePound_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    value += 1;
    print();

}

private void twoPound_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    value += 2;
    print();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code you are not adding numbers, example:
you have this code:

```
private void tenP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    balance.Clear();
    balance.Text = balance.Text + "0.10";

}
```

the value of balance.Text = "0.10"

then, if the next code is executed:

```
private void fiftyP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    balance.Clear();
    balance.Text = balance.Text + "0.50";
}
```

the value of balance.Text = "0.50"

the point is that your are trying to add strings not numbers and you are clearing your previous value